# Calculate $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{\frac{\int_{0}^{x} \frac{\sin(t)}{t}-\tan(x)}{2x(1-\cos(x))}}$ using Mclaurin polynomial

Tags: limits

How would I calculate $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}{\frac{\int_{0}^{x} \frac{\sin(t)}{t}-\tan(x)}{2x(1-\cos(x))}}$$ using a Maclaurin polynomial? For the integral in the numerator, the polynomial doesn't seem to exist beyond degree 1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no trouble with the integral. Just write down the expansion of $\sin t$, divide by $t$, and integrate term by term.

In detail, $\sin t$ has expansion $t-t^3/6+\cdots$. Divide by $t$. We get $1-t^2/6+\cdots$. Integrate from $0$ to $x$. We get $x-x^3/18+\cdots$. If you are worried about what happens at $0$, don't. The limit is $1$. Anyway, the integral is not sensitive to the value of the function at just one point.

You will need a bit of the expansion of $\tan x$. Possibly you could just compute the terms (you will need up to the $x^3$ term) from the definition. You will need the first three derivatives of $\tan x$.  There are other ways, like working with $\sin x$ and $\cos x$.

Comment: I just realized why I was confused. Computed a certain part wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We have, for $x$ near zero,
$$
\sin t = t-t^3/6+o(t^5), \ \ \tan x =x+x^3/3+o(x^5),\ \ \cos x =1-x^2/2+o(x^4).
$$
Then 
$$
\frac{\int_0^x\frac{\sin t}t dt-\tan x}{2x(1-\cos x)}
=\frac{\int_0^x(1-t^2/6+o(t^4))dt-(x+x^3/3+o(x^5))}{2x(x^2/2+o(x^4))}
=\frac{x-x^3/18+o(x^5)-(x+x^3/3+o(x^5))}{2x(x^2/2+o(x^4))}
=\frac{-7x^3/18+o(x^5)}{x^3+o(x^5))}
=\frac{-7/18+o(x^2)}{1+o(x^2))}
\to -\frac7{18}.
$$